# I want to know the difference between Sheet1 and setting worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of script that’s in module1 that checks if an option button is clicked.

The option button is placed in Sheet1, name “Info”, so I thought the script below would work

```
Sub checkClicked()
    dim Page as worksheet
    set Page as worksheets(“Info”)
    Debug.print Page.optClicked 
End sub
```

But when I did it like this it says method or data member not found. It would only work if I replace it with

```
… 
Debug.print Sheet1.optClicked
…
```

Can anyone give me an insight why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

Think of Sheet1 as a "subclass" of "worksheet" - when you add controls to the sheet you're adding new members.  A generic worksheet object doesn't have a member which represents your option button, whereas Sheet1 does.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim sht1 As Sheet1

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sht1 = Sheet1

    Debug.Print sht.optClicked  'error
    Debug.Print sht1.optClicked 'OK

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set Page = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Info") should work. I think worksheets is no real property in VBA...
```

Also, your debug print code looks weird, use debug.print("bla")..
Do you have Option explicit activated?

Comment: thanks Christian, but your way still doesnt work for me. I can debug using debug.print("bla")... as well as debug.print "bla" . humm i didnt turn on option explicit.

Comment: What kind of errormessage do you get?
Is "Info" correctly written? If not, try simply:
Set Page = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1) that sets the page to page one.
What kind of data is optklicked?
In any case use option explicit, all kinds of small errors crop up if you do not (search stackoverflow for explanation)

Answer (score 1):

Try `Set Page = Worksheets("Info")` and do NOT use these curly `“”` quotes - just in case (for Excel formulas this DOES matter).

Comment: thanks Peter, I did try Set Page = Worksheets("Info"), instead of set Page as Worksheets("Info"), but it still doesnt have the optClicked data member

Answer (score 0):

The argument within Worksheets is the name of the worksheet you are interested in, i.e. "Sheet1".

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, I set it so it's ...Set Page = Worksheets("Sheet1")... and even 
Set Page = activeworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 but it still doesn't recognize that,

Answer (score 0):

Other approach: the ActiveX controls on sheet are accessible from two collections: **Shapes** and **OLEObjects**. You could use the **OLEObjects collection** to get access to your checkbox.

```
Sub checkClicked()
    Dim Page As Worksheet
    Set Page = Worksheets("Info")

    ' 1/ ActiveX check box in Shapes collection
    Dim myShape As Shape
    Set myShape = Page.Shapes("optClicked")
    ' --------------------------------------

    ' 2/ ActiveX check box in OLEObjects collection
    Dim myOLEObject As OLEObject
    Set myOLEObject = Page.OLEObjects("optClicked")

    ' Use Object property to get access to your check box
    Dim myCheckBox As Variant
    Set myCheckBox = myOLEObject.Object

    If (TypeOf myCheckBox Is MSForms.CheckBox) Then
      Debug.Print myCheckBox.value
    End If
End Sub
```